# Creating Subcolumns in Dataset

Tags: r, arrays, dataframe, dplyr, group-by

I need help creating a new dataframe in R from a given dataset. The given dataset is a compilation of people in various countries who have answered a survey about cultural values. This dataset has columns like Country_Name, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4. For each of these questions, one can answer 1,2,3,4,5,6 to specificy how important that cultural value is to them. Not all countries have the same options for answer choices, like some countries have only 1-4 available while some have 1-6.

I need help creating a new dataframe from the given dataset that will have countries at the far left of the dataset with each individual question as a column, and each possible response 1-4 or 1-6 or whatever possible response being a subcolumn. I also need the count of each of these possible responses. Attached are pictures of the dataset I am working with and a picture of what I want to create.
Variable I want to use is B_COUNTRY_ALPHA
[image: Variable I want to use is B_COUNTRY_ALPHA]

Here you can see each question in the dataset is an individual column
[image: Here you can see each question in the dataset is an individual column]

This is the dataframe I want to create:
[image: This is the dataframe I want to create:]

I can provide the dataset in csv format or I can give you direct directions to find the dataset if you need the dataset to provide a clear explanation

So far I have tried using double group_by and I have tried creating an array, but that has not worked well as I do not know the proper syntax. This is what I have tried so far:

testtable1 <- WVSDATASET %>%
group_by(B_COUNTRY_ALPHA, Q1) %>%
summarize(
Ques1 = length(Q1),
Ques2 = length(Q2),
Ques3 = length(Q3),
Ques4 = length(Q4),
Ques5 = length(Q5),
Ques6 = length(Q6),
Ques7 = length(Q7),
)

This is the code I have to model what I'm looking for. While it does provide the count of all responses in Q1, it only applies to Q1.
[As you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66gs5.png)
I want code that will find the count of all responses (1-4 or 1-6) for all questions and not have to manually write Q1, Q2, Q3, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A great way to share example data is by running `dput(head(WVSDATASET))`, which creates a code recipe to recreate the first few lines of your data, w/ structure + data formats, and then you can paste that output into the body of your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can see what you're after.  The photo of the whiteboard suggests you want an overall table with rows that are countries and columns for each question, then within each cell of that table, you essentially want a subtable with rows of possible responses (1-4 or 1-6) and a 2nd column with frequency of each.   A number of packages (including data.table, dplyr)can help count items by groups.  The rtables package is set up to prepare complex tables like this (e.g. FDA submission of clinical trial data).

I'll second John Spring's comment of sharing (or making up) some data. Without that it's harder to be more specific.  In a general, you could set up an rtables table structure to match.  This code is not intended to be a complete answer, but to point you in general direction:

```
lyt <-  basic_table(show_colcounts = TRUE) %>%
    split_cols_by("Question", split_fun = add_combo_levels(combodf)) %>%
    split_rows_by("Country")%>%
    split_rows_by("AnswerLevel") %>%
    analyze("QuestionLevels")

build_table(lyt, Data)
```

https://insightsengineering.github.io/rtables/main/

Good luck with this!